# Which archive for mpi with boost?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

I'm intending to use Boost::MPI to send and receive some data - mostly large arrays of numbers - between a master and a worker process. Right now, I'm importing text_iarchive.hpp and text_oarchive.hpp as the archive implementation. Are these the best ones to use for this application? Does it matter which one I use if the data is BOOST_IS_MPI_DATATYPE?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't care about the archive implementation, it's transparent. You just make the types itself serializable, by including the specific serialization header for the type or implementing `serialize`. In neither case you see the used archive.

Internally, Boost.MPI uses [`boost::mpi::packed_oarchive`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/mpi/packed_oarchive.hpp).

For large array of numbers, you should indeed make sure that the type `is_mpi_datatype`. Then there is no serialization which means much better performance.